# How to contract two tensors in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

With the package `itensor` I can contract tensors using indices, but how do I contract two tensors if I have the components? For example, if I try to contract the following tensors:

```
load("itensor");
m: matrix([1,2],[3,4]);
l: matrix([5,6],[7,8]);

show(m([],[i,j])*l([i,j],[]));
```

nothing is displayed.